# MySQL checking if user last logins timestamps are always less than session timestamps

Tags: mysql, sql, join, subquery

Hopefully, the image/diagram helps explain what I'm trying to do...

Been going round-and-round, nothing seems to work, this is the my most recent attempt:

```
SELECT * FROM sessions
   (
       SELECT sessions.timestamp AS stimestamp
                     users.last_login AS ulastlogin
       FROM sessions, users
       WHERE  sessions.user_id = users.user_id
       ORDER BY sessions.timestamp DESC LIMIT 1
   )
WHERE ulastlogin < stimestamp;
```

I'd like to have a SQL query to check to make sure that users' last_login timestamps are always larger (more recent) than the actual user sessions...

[image: MySQL table scheme, sudo code and desired results]

Comment: This sounds back to front. Login precedes and creates the session. How can the login timestamp be later than the session timestamp? And if it's back to front, it's inherent. What exactly are you trying to accomplish here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone at work helped me and I ended-up just using this... Thanks D.B.!!!

I did have to de-dupe in Excel, but other than that, it seemed to do the trick:

```
SELECT * FROM users, sessions
WHERE sessions.timestamp > unix_timestamp() - 3600*24
AND users.user_id = sessions.user_id
AND users.last_login < sessions.timestamp;
```

It grabs what I need for the last 24 hours, so I can do sub-selections by date range.